# Is `x-- > 0 && array[x]` well-defined behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, post-increment

Can I use `x` on both sides of a boolean expression when I post-increment it on the left side?

The line in question is:

```
 if(x-- > 0 && array[x]) { /* … use x … */ }
```

Is that defined through the standard? Will array[x] use the new value of `x` or the old one?

Comment: remember to keep your code clean for others to read, even if is well defined it may introduce an issue if somebody later changes or adds to the expression. Just my 2c

Comment: Even if it may be well defined, you should not use such kind code. You may understand it as you write it, but the next peson may not.

Comment: this code is not too bad after all. i've seen worse code in the linux kernel :D

Comment: Please specify the type of `x`. If x is an integer then yes. If it is a class depends on if somebody was stupid enough to define the && operator for the class (against every coding convention known).

Comment: @knittl "not too bad after all"-- Poor praise indeed. I wouldn't judge my code against the linux kernel. We don't want to write code that is "not too bad". We want to write code that is simple and obvious, clear and clean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends.

If `&&` is the usual short-circuiting logical operator, then it's fine because there's a sequence point. `array[x]` will use the new value.

If `&&` is a user (or library) defined overloaded operator, then there is no short-circuit, and also no guarantee of a sequence point between the evaluation of `x--` and the evaluation of `array[x]`. This looks unlikely given your code, but without context it is not possible to say for sure. I think it's possible, with careful definition of `array`, to arrange it that way.

This is why it's almost always a bad idea to overload `operator&&`.

By the way, `if ((x > 0) && array[--x])` has a very similar effect (again, assuming no operator overloading shenanigans), and in my opinion is clearer. The difference is whether or not `x` gets decremented past 0, which you may or may not be relying on.

Comment: Since when can you overload `operator&&` at all?

Comment: it's the boolean operator && and it's not overloaded

Comment: @Steve: Even if && were overloaded it would still be defined behavior, no?

Comment: @Zack: certainly since the C++ standard was finalized, I don't know about before that.

Comment: @Armen: I think not, although I'm not entirely sure in this case. My thinking is that suppose `x` is an integer type, and `array` is an array of some type T for which a `bool operator&&(bool, const T&)` overload exists. Then there's no sequence point between the evaluation of `x--` and the evaluation of `array[x]` (because none of that is overloaded), hence undefined behavior. I may have missed something which makes it defined, though - I'm a C++ user rather than a C++ compiler-writer, so if I'm going to err I try to err on the side of assuming something is undefined until proven otherwise.

Comment: @Armen: if both x is int and array is an array then it's impossible to overload for them.

Comment: @Armen: it doesn't really matter whether anything is overloaded for `x` or for `array`. I mention it only because if they're not overloaded, then we can be sure there are no sequence points other than for the `&&`, which simplifies things a bit. The issue is whether anything is overloaded for `array[x]`.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is well defined. `&&` introduces a sequence point.

Comment: Huh, I have the feeling that you or others are using some feed like Twitter in order to answer so darned fast. When I first see a question it's generally already answered... ?

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach, click the "questions" link once in a second

Comment: @Alf: When I saw this question it was unanswered and so I answered it. The trick is : Refresh the "New questions" page at least once in 10 seconds. `;-)`

Comment: so, `array[x]` uses the old or the new value?

Comment: hmm I thought it would get the old value... oh well

Comment: @VJovic the built-in && operator is short-circuiting.  This means that the second half of the expression is *only* evaluated after the first half has also succeeded.  That's why "if (X != NULL && X->foo == 2)" is valid.

Comment: @KazDragon I wanted to say that I didn't know that the `&&` introduces a sequence point. Anyway I find that code quite awful. Have 2 ifs is more clear and easier to debug. *Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.* This holds specially if someone else has to debug your code, because not all people have the same level of knowledge and experience.

Comment: @VJovic Preaching to the choir, here.  I'd say what I wrote is actually quite idiomatic: testing the LHS, using the result in the RHS is a very common pattern.  Actually modifying the LHS in the process, however, requires scrutiny and hits your complaint.